# If we say "an object is at rest," can we also say "the object is moving at a constant velocity?"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, terminology, velocity

If we say "an object is at rest," can we also say "the object is moving at a constant velocity?"

Of course, the constant velocity would be zero, so it's mathematically sound. However, the wording throws us off, because we have specified that the object is **moving**, which should indicate a **non-zero constant velocity.** Besides that, how is the object moving if it is at rest?

Question source:

[image]

Comment: It's probably something your teacher overlooked. I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: how is 3 not a constant velocity?

Comment: $v$ is the derivative of $s$, and since (3) is a linear graph, you are correct in saying that velocity is constant in (3). Notice that velocity is also constant in (1).

Comment: It would have been more clear if instead of "**moving** at constant velocity" the option would have been: "**has** constant velocity". Being at rest is a particular case of having constant velocity.
Of course, according to the object 3 frame of reference, **he is the one at rest** and object 1 is moving with constant velocity.

Comment: Was 1 *and* 3 an option?

Comment: @AdrianHoward It wanted them to pick 1 and 3 probably. It says pick the curve(s)

Comment: So you're asking whether zero is a constant?

Comment: @WillO That's not what they are asking at all

Comment: @garyp Yes, you could choose any, multiple, or none of the four choices.

Comment: This is a question where you just ask your teacher. We can't speak to what your teacher could have meant.

Answer (score 1):

> If we say "an object is at rest," can we also say "the object is
>   moving at a constant velocity?"

Not with respect to the same reference frame. I am sitting on a train moving at constant velocity with respect to the tracks. Am I "at rest" or am I moving at "constant velocity"? The answer is I am at rest in the reference frame of the train but I am moving at constant velocity with respect to someone on the tracks observing me through the train window.

As far as the diagrams go, just keep in mind that the velocity of the object is the rate of change in its position in the reference frame where $S(t)$ is measured, This is the derivative $\frac{dS(t)}{dt}$, which is the instantaneous slope of the $S(t)$ curve.

Hope this helps.